# Find the nearest Date, given a TargetDate and Day of Week

Tags: code-golf, date

Find the nearest Date to a TargetDate for a given Day of Week.

For example, given a date of `20161219` and a day of week of `Friday (6)`, the answer is `20161216`.

Another example, given a date of `20161219` and a day of week of `Wednesday (4)`, the answer is `20161221`.

A final example, given a date of `20161219` and a day of week of `Monday (2)`, the answer is `20161219`.

**Rules:**

- The Date format for the input and output must match. In the examples, I used `yyyymmdd`, but you may use any format as long as the year (at least two digits), month, and day of month are "human readable".
- Day of Week is input as an integer. In my example, Sunday is the first day of the week, therefore it is day of week number `1`. You can have any Day of Week numbering, as long as you note it when it differs from the example.
- Years 1970 through 2030 must be accommodated.
- Common language date tools and libraries are allowed, but street cred is given to those that choose not to use them.
- Least number of *bytes* wins.

Comment: Could answers take the date in a different form if convenient? Also the days of the week also seen inconvenient for languages that take Monday to be the first day of the week

Comment: Yeah, the strict format requirements make this task more about parsing/converting/formatting, than about the actual date finding. Would have IMO been better to specify it along the lines of "*You can accept the date and weekday in any reasonable format, as long as you use the same format for input and output.*". But since a bunch of people have already submitted answers,I guess it has to be keep it as it is now.

Comment: @smls I agree. Lesson learned for next time.

Comment: @BrettVanderVeen I don't think it is too late to relax the requirements. You can just add a comment to each of the (currently 8) answers about the updated spec. I've done such on occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 46 bytes

```
{~first *.day-of-week==$^b,Date.new($^a)-3..*}
```

A lambda that accepts two arguments: A date string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and a weekday number between `1`=Monday and `7`=Sunday.

Explanation:

```
                           Date.new($^a)       # Construct Date object from first argument.
                                        -3     # Subtract 3 days.
                                          ..*  # Construct a Range from that, to infinity.
  first                   ,                    # Iterate the range, and return first date...
        *.day-of-week==$^b                     # whose weekday number equals the second arg.
```

---

Using the date and weekday format used in the examples, it would be 88 bytes:

```
{S:g/\-//with ~first *.day-of-week==($^b-2)%7+1,Date.new(|($^a~~/(....)(..)(..)/))-3..*}
```

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Comment: @BrettVanderVeen: Updated.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 83 bytes

```perl6
->$_,\w{~(Date.new(|m/(....)(..)(..)/)-3...*.day-of-week%7+1==w)[*-1]~~{S:g/"-"//}}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#ZVFNT4NAEL3zK0aCAhUWQUNTCZ68ePGiNzVNA4OS8tGyS2mD8NfrgNBi3GSzM2/ezLyZLTnCzmWBJ5VkvSIXniSlB7gKkpyTZ4YrgeAfzQdlabxXdas9EsAyrLTv1NIYHV0brqWbt@TPWLg6mHlkVojry/m17fuV/jYz7Y@2rV/uPy3ZlC2raY5RXkASZ8g1HWoJoMwS5ByUJdSwKQWoqgcZ7gU0EkVJlKZ0agxlUt9QcL/BQGCogw@syouQex09jmDKY89likUcwEXbwlMmgHpP4z1uMzbvlQDwdbyB7bau4iQhETssQGCRxlm3jioWX7ACSoc8gj6dXnlaT268vk6nv7PGEZQCeZkI0vpnwf8HOw0xzsdCjGhZ4SAw5mMt48whc9k1A0zoN3@J3Sbp71RQjSGhl9McnRvbtR17AS4MpiudsLsBc@wz5oy8hXQGJ/H5Dw)

### Expanded

```perl6
->     # pointy block lambda
  $_,
  \w
{
  ~(  # turn into a Str

    Date.new( |m/(....)(..)(..)/ ) - 3 # three days earlier
    ...                                # generate a sequence
    *.day-of-week % 7 + 1 == w         # stop when the right day is found

  )[*-1]  # the last one

  ~~      # apply the following block

  {
    S:g/"-"//  # remove ｢-｣
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```
(s,n,d=new Date(s))=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+(n+9-d.getDay())%7-3)&&d.toISOString().slice(0,10)
```

Uses `%Y-%m-%d` date format. If `%a %b %d %Y` is an acceptable date format, then for 82 bytes:

```
(s,n,d=new Date(s))=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+(n+9-d.getDay())%7-3)&&d.toDateString()
```

I could save a further 2 bytes by requiring Sunday = 10 to Saturday = 16, but that's a silly day of week mapping. Previous <s>142</s> 141 bytes (thanks to @Guedes) version that used the specific YYYYMMDD date format, with its explanation:

```
(s,n,d=new Date(s.replace(/(?=..(..)?$)/g,'-')))=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+(n+9-d.getDay())%7-3)&&d.toISOString().replace(/-(..)-(..).*/,'$1$2')
```

This feels far too long. Explanation: First, inserts `-`s into the date to get it into ISO format which `new Date` can then parse. Then, compares the desired day with the actual day to get a value between `-3` and `3` for the actual offset. The magic `9` comes from `7` (because `%` is CPU modulo, not true modulo) plus `3` (for the `-3` offset) minus `1` (because `n` is 1-indexed and `getDay` is 0-indexed). The date is then converted back into ISO format and the unwanted characters removed.

Comment: You can save one byte changing the first replace to `.replace(/(?=..(..)?$)/g,'-')`

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 50

```bash
date -d$1+$[($2-`date -d$1 +%u`+9)%7-3]day +%Y%m%d
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU1AyMjA0MzQytFQwU0LimCBzjJSsFVLyuYpTSxR0dRVUYNr/pySWpCropqgYaqtEa6gY6SbABRS0VUsTtC01Vc11jWNTEiuB/EjVXNWU/yn5ean/AQ).

- `date -d$1 +%u` gives the day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday
- This is subtracted from the input day of week to give a difference of day indexes.  We want to add a factor between in the range [-3, 3] to the input date to get the closest date, so we add a magic factor 9, take the modulo 7, then subtract 3.  The magic factor 9 is `3 + 7 - 1`.  The 3 adjusts the input range for range [-3, 3], and is subtracted again after the modulo.  The 7 is required because bash modulo is the same as CPU modulo and can give -ve results - adding 7 adjusts into the right range.  The -1 is because in the input, 1 is Sunday, but with the %u output, 1 is Monday.
- The outer `date` then parses `<input date> + <magic factor>days` and presents it in the YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>150</s> 149 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
lambda s,n,t='%Y%m%d':[d for d in[datetime.strptime(s,t)+timedelta(o-3)for o in range(7)]if(n-2)%7==d.weekday()][0].strftime(t)
```

Oouuf, 149. **[repl.it](https://repl.it/Ettx/1)**

Unnamed function that takes a string `s`, the date as specified (using format string `t='%Y%m%d'` for both input and output) and a number in [1,7], `n`.
Inspects the seven days from three days prior to three days after that given for the day of the week requested.
The week in `datetime` starts on Monday and is zero based, so the test is `(n-2)%7==d.weekday()`.

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

### R, <strike>119 77</strike> 56 bytes

Unnamed function that takes two inputs, the date `D` (string) and the day `d` (numeric).

```
function(D,d,s=-3:3+as.Date(D))s[lubridate::wday(s)==d]
```

Uses the function `wday()` from the `lubridate` package. It can conveniently convert `Date` objects into week days with `1` being treated as Sunday by default.

Edit: I/O is now the default of the `as.Date()` function: `"YYYY-mm-dd"`

**Ungolfed and Explained**

```
function(D,d){
    D=as.Date(D);            # Format input date
    s=-3:3+D;                # Generate sequence of +- 3 days
    s[lubridate::wday(s)==d] # Match the weekday that equals to target day                                    
}
```

Edit: Now creates a sequence of `+-3` days for which any given weekday is guaranteed to be found in. Subsequently we only have to match one day which made the problem much easier.

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Comment: @BrettVanderVeen Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

## SAS Macro Language, 110 Bytes

```
%macro s(d,a);%put %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(week.&a.,%eval(%sysfunc(putn(&d,8.))-4),1)),yymmddn8.));%mend;
```

A terrible golfing language but here's the explanation (from the inside out):

Create a macro `s` that accepts a date input `d` and a numeric weekday `a`. Then `%eval(%sysfunc(putn(&d,8.))-4)` converts the date to a SAS numeric date and decrements it by 4 days. The `intnx` function then returns the next occurrence of the specified weekday. `putn` then formats the date back to yyyymmdd and `%put` prints the output to the log.

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>85</s> 49 bytes

```
#~DatePlus~Mod[#2-#~DateValue~"ISOWeekDay",7,-3]&
```

The input format for dates is either a list like `{2016, 12, 16}` or an actual `DateObject` (I think a few others work as well, but I've tested these). In either case, the output format will match automatically. The day numbering starts from `1` on Mondays.

The idea is to compute the difference between the input weekday and the target weekday with `#2-#~DateValue~"ISOWeekDay"` and then to map it into `[-3, 3]` using a modulo with offset (i.e. `Mod[...,7,-3]`). The result is simply added to the input date (the default unit for date object addition is days).

Comment: FYI, I eased up on the date and day of week format rules. Feel free to resubmit.

Comment: @BrettVanderVeen thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

## Shell + GNU date, 43 bytes

```sh
date +%F -d$1-3day`date -d$1+$2day +%w`day
```

I wish I could explain how this works, but there was so much trial-and-error tweaking it no longer makes sense even to me!  We start by subtracting three days so that adding a number in range 0-6 gives the nearest.   But why adding the desired weekday to the target date gives the necessary offset has slipped my grasp.

Input as in the question; output format is YYYY-MM-DD.

[Online test](https://tio.run/##PU@9DoMgEN55ihswaoxG6F/s1qVjl64OpQWjCzZAY4jx2SmI8Rsu9/0c3L2Z7h2TehIqy2fHmRFQJHcoOSblgTP7WqVAC0w99@7kNesWhLpRwWoPEmhNzoSSxjf0WJP6hPiIwCOGbMjMpKouy6puZsBXDdJ0kD4EU0IbSBoNZoREw6CvkEK7JzfgbNvpycxP@bcL7Esbl7vlgIO9D8Xjohiq3f6XMSI@/YgCc38)